# Show that the set $\{v_n\} \subset l^2$, $v_j$ is orthonormal.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Show that the set $\{v_n\} \subset l^2$, where $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_n-e_{n+1})$ if $n$ is odd and $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_n+e_{n-1})$ if $n$ even is orthonormal.

So $\{v_n\}$ is orthonormal, if $\langle v_n,v_m\rangle=1 \,if \,n=m \,and =0 \,if n \neq m$.

So we have four case, (1) $n$-odd, $m$-odd, (2) $n$-odd, $m$-even, (3) $n$-even, $m$-odd, (4) $n$-even, $m$-even. But it is enough to show cases (1), (2), and (4) since (2) and (3) are the same.

UPDATE:

\null
Suppose $n,m$ are both odd,
$$\langle v_n,v_m \rangle = \frac{1}{2}(e_n-e_{n+1})(e_m-e_{m+1})=\frac{1}{2}(e_ne_m-e_{n+1}e_m-e_ne_{m+1}+e_{n+1}e_{m+1})=\frac{1}{2}(1-0-0+1)=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

\null
Suppose $n$ is odd, and $m$ is even,
$$\langle v_n,v_m \rangle = \frac{1}{2}(e_n-e_{n+1})(e_m+e_{m-1})=\frac{1}{2}(e_ne_m-e_{n+1}e_m +e_ne_{m-1}-e_{n+1}e_{m-1})=\frac{1}{2}(1-0-0+0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

\null
Suppose $n,m$ are both even,
$$\langle v_n,v_m \rangle = \frac{1}{2}(e_n+e_{n-1})(e_m+e_{m-1})=\frac{1}{2}(e_ne_m+e_{n-1}e_m+e_ne_{m-1}+e_{n-1}e_{m-1})=\frac{1}{2}(1+0+0+1)=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $e_n e_k = \delta_{nk}$, where $\delta$ is a Kronecker delta, i.e.

$$\delta_{nk}=\begin{cases}1,&n=k,\\0,&n\ne k.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am not familiar with the Kronecker delta. What do I do with this?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown I edited the post.

Comment: So what if we have $e_{n+1}e_m$ then it is equal to 0?

Comment: If $n+1\ne m$, then yes.

Comment: So $\langle v_n,v_m \rangle = \frac{1}{2}(e_n-e_{n+1})(e_m-e_{m+1})=\frac{1}{2}(e_ne_m-e_{n+1}e_m-e_ne_{m+1}+e_{n+1}e_{m+1})=\frac{1}{2}(1-0-0+1)=\frac{2}{2}=1$, that is it for that case?